Why isn't my data updating in child composables?
Im collecting data from my db in my viewmodel. I know its being updated in BottomSheetEditContent, but i don't know how to make it show its's value (the one collected from viewmodel) in child components. Collected value should be shown as initial value in Textfields and in the Switch.
private const val titleMaxSize = 200
private const val descriptionMaxSize = 500

@Composable
fun EditCollectionBottomSheet(
    viewModel: DcodeViewModel,
    sheetState: SheetState,
) {
    val coroutine = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val dismiss = {
        coroutine.launch {
            sheetState.hide()
        }
        viewModel.changeEditDialogVisibility()
    }

    val currentTitle by viewModel.currentTitle.collectAsState()
    val collection by viewModel.currentCollection.collectAsState()
    Log.d(UI_TEST,currentTitle)

/*    LaunchedEffect(key1 = currentTitle) {
        title = currentTitle
        collected = collection
    }*/

    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = { dismiss() },
        sheetState = sheetState,
        dragHandle = { BottomSheetDefaults.HiddenShape },
    ) {
        BottomSheetEditContent(viewModel, { dismiss() })
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomSheetEditContent( //TODO FIX THIS RECEIVING THE LAST COLLECTION INSTEAD OF THE CURRENT
    viewModel: DcodeViewModel,
    dismiss: () -> Unit,
) {
    val willBeAutomaticallySelected = LocalStrings.current.theWorkingListWillBeAutomaticallySelectedForFutureCodeAdditions
    val textColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
    val collection by viewModel.currentCollection.collectAsState()

    var newTitle by remember { mutableStateOf(collection?.title ?: "") }
    var newDescription by remember { mutableStateOf(collection?.listDescription ?: "") }
    var isMarked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    Column {
        BottomSheetEditTopBar(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            dismiss = { dismiss() },
            newTitle = newTitle,
            newDescription = newDescription,
            isMarked = isMarked,
            collection = collection
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            TitleField(focusRequester = focusRequester, currentTitle = newTitle, onTitleChange = { modifiedTitle -> newTitle = modifiedTitle })
            DescriptionField(currentDescription = newDescription, onDescriptionChange = { modifiedDesc -> newDescription = modifiedDesc })
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(15.dp)
                    .background(Color.Transparent)
            )
            IsMarkedSwitch(textColor, isMarked, onMarkedSwitch = {modifiedMarked -> isMarked = modifiedMarked})
            Text(
                text = willBeAutomaticallySelected,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(Padding.BOTTOM_INFO),
                color = textColor.copy(alpha = 0.7f)
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun IsMarkedSwitch(
    textColor: Color,
    currentlyMarked: Boolean,
    onMarkedSwitch: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val textContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer
    val onBackground = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
    val markAsWorkingList = LocalStrings.current.markAsAWorkingList
    var newMarked by remember {
        mutableStateOf(currentlyMarked)
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .background(onBackground),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(text = markAsWorkingList, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp), color = textColor)

        Switch(
            colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(checkedThumbColor = textContainerColor),
            checked = newMarked,
            onCheckedChange = {
                newMarked = it
                onMarkedSwitch(it)
            },
            modifier = Modifier.imePadding()
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun DescriptionField(currentDescription: String, onDescriptionChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    var newDescription by remember {
        mutableStateOf(currentDescription)
    }

    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
            .heightIn(140.dp)
            .imePadding()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
        value = newDescription,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= descriptionMaxSize) {
                newDescription = it
                onDescriptionChange(it)
            }
        },
        placeholder = { Text(text = LocalStrings.current.description) },
        supportingText = {
            Text(
                text = "${newDescription.length}/$descriptionMaxSize",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.End
            )
        },
        maxLines = 4
    )
}

@Composable
private fun TitleField(focusRequester: FocusRequester, currentTitle: String, onTitleChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    val title = LocalStrings.current.title
    val cannotBeEmpty = LocalStrings.current.titleCannotBeEmpty
    val errorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
    var newTitle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(currentTitle)
    }

    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
            .height(100.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
        value = newTitle,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= titleMaxSize) {
                newTitle = it
                onTitleChange(it)
            }
        },
        placeholder = {
            Column {
                Text(text = title, fontSize = 16.sp)
                Text(text = cannotBeEmpty, fontSize = 12.sp, color = errorColor)
            }
        },
        supportingText = {
            Text(
                text = "${newTitle.length}/$titleMaxSize",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.End
            )
        },
        maxLines = 2,
    )
}

@Composable
fun BottomSheetEditTopBar(
    viewModel: DcodeViewModel,
    dismiss: () -> Unit,
    newTitle: String,
    newDescription: String,
    isMarked: Boolean,
    collection: DcodeList?
) {
    val oldTitle = collection?.title ?: ""
    val editList = LocalStrings.current.editList
    val cancel = LocalStrings.current.cancel

    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        title = { Text(text = editList, fontSize = 17.sp) },
        navigationIcon = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = { dismiss() },
                content = { Text(text = cancel) }
            )
        },
        actions = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = { updateAndDismiss(newTitle, newDescription, viewModel, oldTitle, isMarked, dismiss) },
                content = { Text(text = LocalStrings.current.edit) }
            )
        },
    )
}

private fun updateAndDismiss(
    newTitle: String,
    newDescription: String,
    viewModel: DcodeViewModel,
    oldTitle: String,
    isMarked: Boolean,
    dismiss: () -> Unit
) {
    if (newTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
        val formattedNewTitle = newTitle.trimStart()
        val formattedNewDescription = newDescription.trimStart()
        viewModel.updateCollection(oldTitle, formattedNewTitle, formattedNewDescription, isMarked)
        dismiss()
    }
}


private object Padding {
    val BOTTOM_INFO = PaddingValues(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, top = 3.dp)

}

class DcodeViewModel(
    private val dao: DcodeDao,
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>,
    application: Application,
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val CURRENT_LANGUAGE_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("LANGUAGE")

    private val currentLanguageFlow: Flow<String> = dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        preferences[CURRENT_LANGUAGE_KEY] ?: "en"
    }
    private val _currentLanguage = MutableStateFlow("")
    val currentLanguage = _currentLanguage.asStateFlow()

    private val _currentHex = MutableStateFlow("")
    val currentHex = _currentHex.asStateFlow()

    private val _dcodesCollections = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<DcodeList>())
    val dcodesCollections = _dcodesCollections.asStateFlow()

    private val _dcodeList = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Dcode>())
    val dcodeList = _dcodeList.asStateFlow()

    private val _currentCollection = MutableStateFlow<DcodeList?>(null)
    val currentCollection = _currentCollection.asStateFlow()

    
    private val _isTorchOn = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isTorchOn = _isTorchOn.asStateFlow()

    private val _isAddDialogVisible = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isAddDialogVisible = _isAddDialogVisible.asStateFlow()

    private val _isEditDialogVisible = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isEditDialogVisible = _isEditDialogVisible.asStateFlow()

    private val _currentTitle = MutableStateFlow("") // Use MutableStateFlow

    var canUseGpu: Boolean = false
    var numberOfThreads: Int = 0

    init {
        checkUser()
        getCurrentLanguage()
        getAllData()
    }

    private fun checkUser() {
        canUseGpu = CompatibilityList().isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice
        numberOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    }

    private fun getAllData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dao.getAllDcodeListsWithDcodes().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect { listWithDcodes ->
                val collectionList = listWithDcodes.map { it.parentList }
                val dcodeList = listWithDcodes.flatMap { it.dcodeList }

                _dcodesCollections.update { collectionList }
                _dcodeList.update { dcodeList }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getCurrentLanguage() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            currentLanguageFlow.collect { language ->
                _currentLanguage.update { language }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun editActive(collectionName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (!dao.isCurrentMarked(collectionName)) {
                dao.changeActiveCollection(collectionName)
            }
        }
    }

    fun checkOptions(): Interpreter.Options {
        val options =
            Interpreter.Options().apply {
                val compatList = CompatibilityList()
                if (!canUseGpu) { // ! DOESN'T WORK WITH GPU
                    val delegateOptions = compatList.bestOptionsForThisDevice
                    addDelegate(GpuDelegate(delegateOptions))
                    Log.d(ALPHANUMERIC_CLASSIFICATION, "Classifier runs with GPU ")
                } else {
                    numThreads = numberOfThreads / 2
                    Log.d(ALPHANUMERIC_CLASSIFICATION, "Classifier runs on ${this.numThreads} threads")
                }
            }
        return options
    }

    fun addCollection(collectionName: String, collectionDescription: String? = null, isMarked: Boolean) {
        val newDcodeList = DcodeList(
            title = collectionName,
            listDescription = collectionDescription,
            createdAt = Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
            isWorkingList = isMarked,
        )
        Log.d(VIEWMODEL, newDcodeList.toString())

        viewModelScope.launch {
            dao.addCollection(newDcodeList)
        }
    }

    fun switchTorchState() {
        _isTorchOn.update {
            !_isTorchOn.value
        }

        Log.d(CAMERA_SETTINGS, _isTorchOn.value.toString())
    }

    fun changeAddDialogVisibility() {
        _isAddDialogVisible.value = !_isAddDialogVisible.value
        Log.d(VIEWMODEL, _isAddDialogVisible.value.toString())
    }

    fun changeEditDialogVisibility() {
        _isEditDialogVisible.value = !_isEditDialogVisible.value
        Log.d(VIEWMODEL, _isEditDialogVisible.value.toString())
    }

    fun deleteCollection(collectionName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dao.deleteDcodeList(collectionName)
        }
    }

    fun addDcode(dcode: Dcode) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dao.insertDcode(dcode)
        }
    }

    fun deleteDcodeById(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dao.deleteDcodeById(id)
        }
    }

    fun setCurrentCollection(title: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dao.getDcodeListByTitle(title).flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect{collection ->
                _currentCollection.update { collection }
            }
        }
    }

    fun markAsActive(collectionName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dao.toggleWorkingStatusExclusive(collectionName)
        }
    }

    fun setCurrentLanguage(languageTag: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStore.edit { settings ->
                settings[CURRENT_LANGUAGE_KEY] = languageTag
            }
        }
    }

    fun getCountByCollectionTitle(collectionName: String): Flow<Int> =
        dao.getDcodeCountByCollectionTitle(collectionName)

    fun checkIfMarked(collectionName: String): Flow<Boolean> = dao.getIsWorkingListByName(collectionName)

    fun updateCollection(oldTitle: String, newTitle: String, newDescription: String, isMarked: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (isMarked) {
                editActive(oldTitle)
            }

            dao.updateCollectionAndDcodes(newTitle, newDescription, oldTitle)
        }
    }

    fun putHex(hexValue: String) {
        _currentHex.update {
            hexValue
        }
    }
}

I tried updating it with LaunchedEffect once collection value changes and then passing it but to no affect.
The child components are showing the previous value instead of the current.

We also need to see the view model. Also, please try to reduce your code to a [mre].

One thing you should do before updating your question is to refactor your code to never pass a view model as a parameter. Only pass the content of your collected flows and the functions, like this: EditCollectionBottomSheet(title = currentTitle, collection = collection, onDismiss = viewModel::changeEditDialogVisibility, updateCollection = viewModel::updateCollection, sheetState = ...). That is necessary so the Compose runtime can correctly determine when to recompose. Maybe that's even enough to fix your problem. Please update your question with the refactored code.

Just to make it clear, EditCollectionBottomSheet would need to be declared like this: fun EditCollectionBottomSheet(title: String, collection: DcodeList?, onDismiss: () -> Unit, updateCollection: (String, String, String, Boolean) -> Unit, sheetState: SheetState) {
